# Get list of countries from AVSpeechSynthesisVoice

Tags: swift, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I'm trying to get the `Region Code` found in AVSpeechSynthesisVoice instead of e.g: `en-GB`.

The output I'm aiming for is as follow

[image]

This is my current code, while it works, I feel there must be a more elegant solution and from what I read, split by `-` could product errors for some languages

```swift
let speechVoices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let language = Locale.current.localizedString(forLanguageCode: speechVoices[row].language)!
    let languageCode = speechVoices[row].language

    var regionCodeArray = languageCode.split(separator: "-") // FIXME: buggy may break
    let regionCode = regionCodeArray.removeLast()

    // Must be a more elegant way to get RegionCode
    let country = Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: String(regionCode))

    return "\(language) (\(country ?? ""))"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I thought of another alternative that doesn't require splitting and this is what I got, but I welcome alternative answers or perhaps a comment on my code as I am learning and looking to improve

```swift
let speechVoices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let language = Locale.current.localizedString(forLanguageCode: speechVoices[row].language)!
    let languageCode = speechVoices[row].language

    var regionCode:String = ""
    for region in Locale.isoRegionCodes {
        // Test if provided region codes has voices or not
        if languageCode.contains(region) {
            regionCode = region
        }
    }

    let country = Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: String(regionCode))

    return "\(language) (\(country ?? ""))"
}
```